# Euclidean distance between matrix and vector

Tags: python, numpy

Calculate the euclidean of a vector from each column of another vector.
Is this correct?

```
distances=np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(new_v-val.reshape(10,1)),axis=0))
```

new_v is a matrix.
val.reshape(10,1) is a column vector.
Another other/better ways to do it.

Comment: What's the shape of `new_v`?

Comment: Presumably, it's `(10, n)` for arbitrary n.

Comment: A typical `n` value would inspire us to have some timings :)

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 3):

What you have is correct.  There is a simpler method available in `numpy.linalg`:

```
from numpy.linalg import norm
norm(new_v.T-val, axis=1, ord=2)
```

Comment: Think you are doing it wrong by transposing the 2D array, speaking in terms of performance. If you add a new axis with `val` and then use norm along `axis=0`, you would see improvement : `norm(new_v-val[:,None], axis=0, ord=2)`.

Comment: I ran it few times, it doesn't seem to matter, probably because its working with the transpose that's a view only without making a copy there. So, you are fine I guess.

Comment: Yeah, I had noticed it's slightly faster to reshape the 1-dim vector to a 2-dim column vector, as opposed to transposing the matrix.  But the OP never said that maximum performance was the goal, so I prefer the most readable / numpythonic approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the efficient [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
subs = new_v - val[:,None]
out = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->j',subs,subs))
```

Alternatively, using `(a-b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab` formula -

```
out = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->j',new_v, new_v) + val.dot(val) - 2*val.dot(new_v))
```

If the second axis of `new_v` is a large one, we can also `numexpr` module to compute the `sqrt` part at the end.

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
import numexpr as ne

def einsum_based(new_v, val):
    subs = new_v - val[:,None]
    return np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->j',subs,subs))

def dot_based(new_v, val):
    return np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->j',new_v, new_v) + \
                            val.dot(val) - 2*val.dot(new_v))

def einsum_numexpr_based(new_v, val):
    subs = new_v - val[:,None]
    sq_dists = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',subs,subs)
    return ne.evaluate('sqrt(sq_dists)')

def dot_numexpr_based(new_v, val):
    sq_dists = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',new_v, new_v) + val.dot(val) - 2*val.dot(new_v)
    return ne.evaluate('sqrt(sq_dists)')
```

Timings -

```
In [85]: # Inputs
    ...: new_v = np.random.randint(0,9,(10,100000))
    ...: val = np.random.randint(0,9,(10))


In [86]: %timeit np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(new_v-val.reshape(10,1)),axis=0))
    ...: %timeit einsum_based(new_v, val)
    ...: %timeit dot_based(new_v, val)
    ...: %timeit einsum_numexpr_based(new_v, val)
    ...: %timeit dot_numexpr_based(new_v, val)
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.91 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.1 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.12 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.26 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.43 ms per loop

In [87]: from numpy.linalg import norm

# @wim's solution
In [88]: %timeit norm(new_v.T-val, axis=1, ord=2)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.88 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is slower, longer, and less clear than the OP's original code, imo.

Comment: @wim Added timings if you were curious about performance. About being "clear", well, if I don't know anything about `norm`, I guess I could say the same about other solution(s).

Comment: I used `new_v = np.random.rand(10, 1000)` and `val = np.random.rand(10)`.  Actually, the first method with 2-lines is faster.  I was trying the one-liner method originally.

Comment: The timings are weird for integer input.  You should be using floats for distances, not ints.