# find closest set in N-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

Let's assume I have a numpy array composed of the combinations of all this ranges:

```
A = numpy.arange(0.05, 7.05, 0.5)
B = numpy.arange(0.0,0.75, 0.15 )
C = numpy.arange(8.0, 12.0, 0.15)
D = numpy.arange(-2, 2, 0.15)
E = [0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7]
F = numpy.arange(0.1,2.1, 0.1)
G = [0.5, 1.0, 1.5]
```

The resulting array is called `A` and is 7 lines and 15309000 columns.

now I have this groub:

```
group = [a ,b, c, d, e, f, g] = [1.22, 0.34, 9.45, -1.43, 0.52, 0.23, 0.64]
```

I am looking for a way to find the combination in A that is the closest to the former group in the sense that the selected set (closest combination) would be the group where all the value are the closest to the group to find: a would be the closest value in A, b the closest value in B, etc...

For this particular case, the closest group would be:

```
closest_group = [1.05, 0.3, 9.5, -1.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5]
```

I have found a different answers like with `scipy.signal.KDTree` for example:

```
A[spatial.KDTree(A).query(set)[1]]
```

but unfortunately this does not converge, raising this error:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: Need to define "closest". What is the notion of distance in use?

Comment: FWIW, `set` is a built-in type and function. You should think about naming your variables in another manner, like `my_set`.

Comment: How about something like : `((A-B[:,None])**2).sum(0).argmin()`, where `A` is your (7,15309000) array and `B` is the set array? Alternative with `einsum` and `matrix-multiplication` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/43374851/3293881

Comment: I edited the post for the changed asked in the comments.

Comment: In your explanation, have you reused the name `A`?  The first line of the first block of code is `A = numpy.arange(0.05, 7.05, 0.5)`, but then you say "The resulting array is called `A`...".

Comment: In the `closest_group` answer, where did the first value `1.05` come from?  I don't see that value in the arrays `A`, `B`, etc., that you gave above.